# Найти предыдущий високосный год

Tags: javascript, дата

Какой код нужно написать, чтобы найти **предыдущий** високосный
год используя конструктор `Date` или указывая год самому?

Пытался сделать так:

```js
let now = new Date();
let date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 2, 0);

for (now.getFullYear(), , year--) {
  if (date.getDate() == 29) {
    console.log("Високосный год!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
function prevLeapYear(y) {
  --y // убрать, если надо <= переданного, а не строго <
  y &= ~3
  if (y % 100 === 0 && y % 400 !== 0) y -= 4
  return y
}

var input = document.querySelector('input')
var output = document.querySelector('output')

output.textContent = prevLeapYear(input.valueAsNumber)

input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  output.textContent = e.target.validity.valid
    ? prevLeapYear(e.target.valueAsNumber)
    : "Enter valid year"
})
```

```html
<input type=number value=2022 required min=1 max=10000> <output></output>
```

Comment: Что за `~3`? И `y &= ~3`? 

Comment: @Demon__, округлить вниз до кратного 4. Вот так: `3 = 0b0...0011`, а `~3 = 0b1...1100 = -4`. Применение `& ~3` потрёт 2 младших бита (предварительно число будет сконвертировано в signed int32).

Comment: Благодарю [4 символов]

Comment: Я никак не могу понять к чему это условие на 4 строке. Получается что для 3000 года високосным будет 2996, а следующий високосный уже 3004 (Спустя 8 лет).

Comment: @Nannik, так и есть.

Answer (score 1):

в виде функции

```js
function getPrevLeap(year) {
    while (true) {
        let date = new Date(year--, 2, 0)
        if (date.getDate() === 29){
            return date.getFullYear()
        }
    }
}

console.log(getPrevLeap(2022))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы проверить сделать проверку високосный год или нет, достаточно проверить на делимость на 4

```js
function getLastLeapYear() {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const diff = year % 4;
  return year - diff;
}

console.log(getLastLeapYear());
```

Comment: Неправильно. Делимость на 100 не проверил.

Comment: 1900 % 4 === 0, но это не высокосный

Comment: @Qwertiy  зачем проверять  делимость на 100? При каких обстоятельствах это может пригодиться? явно лишняя проверка

Comment: @entithat  зачем проверять на 1900? При каких обстоятельствах это может пригодиться? явно лишняя проверка

Comment: @Vladimir, ? 1900 - один из тестов. Таким же образом показал, что код нерабочий.

Comment: @Vladimir, *For example, in the Gregorian calendar, each leap year has 366 days instead of 365, by extending February to 29 days rather than the common 28. These extra days occur in each year which is an integer multiple of 4 (except for years evenly divisible by 100, but not by 400). The leap year of 366 days has 52 weeks and two days, hence the year following a leap year will start later by two days of the week.*

Comment: @entithat в вопросе явно написано, что нужно последний високосный год. В реализации отталкиваются от текущей даты. Значит можно сделать вывод, что нужен просто последний год. 1900 год прошел 122 года назад, поэтому нет смысла его проверять в тестах

Comment: @Vladimir, ок, 2600. Высокосный? Нет. 2500? Тоже нет.

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе явно звучит "Как дописать код..." То есть предлагается цикл for, в котором по признаку 29 дней надо выделить високосный год. Пожалуйста:

```
let now = new Date();                //Получаем текущую дату
let year = now.getFullYear();        //Извлекаем год (четыре знака)
const limit = year - 4; //Високосный год бывает раз в 4 года. 4 года - диапазон поиска

for(year; year > limit; --year) {//Изменяя год в пределах диапазона поиска,
    let date = new Date(year, 1, 29);//Подставляем число, присущее високосному году
    let currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    if(currentMonth == 1) { //Если номер месяца не изменился, значит это - високосный год
        console.log('Вот он, високосный год! -- ', year);
    } else {               //Если номер месяца изменился, проходим к предыдущему году...
        console.log('Фига вам, а не високосный год!');
    }
}
```

Используем очень полезную особенность объектов Date - автоисправление. То есть, если задан номер дня больше, чем имеется в месяце, то изменяется номер месяца и номер дня. Кстати, проверка показала, что номера месяцев начинаются с нуля.

Comment: Во-первых, не 4 года, а иногда 8. Во-вторых, надо использовать break, а не условие. Ну или всю проверку в условие поместить. И зачем в предусловии цикла мусор?

Comment: Уважаемый Qwertiy, в вопросе явно указано, что надо отыскать предыдущий високосный год. А 1900 и 2100, которые должны бы были стать високосными, но не стали, достаточно удалены от нас. То есть ваше "во-первых" несколько не к месту. По поводу вашего "во-вторых" я просто растерялся. Ведь в предлагаемом решении я пишу "В вопросе явно звучит "Как дописать код..." То есть предлагается цикл for, в котором по признаку 29 дней надо выделить високосный год". 
Вопрос задал явно начинающий. Я - тоже только 10 часов как подключился к Stackoverflow. Это - мой вариант. Плохо?Предложите автору вопроса свой.

Comment: Ну так что мешает улучшить до нормального варианта, который проще и 1900/2100 учитывает? Ну и то, что автор использует его только для текущей даты (если это вообще так) вовсе не означает, что все остальные, попавшие сюда из гугла - тоже. А вдруг его программа доживёт до 2100?

Comment: Вот, я из твоего кода выкинул несколько лишних мест и добавил `break` - всё работает верно для любых лет: `let now = new Date();
let year = now.getFullYear();
for(; ; --year) {
let date = new Date(year, 1, 29);
let currentMonth = date.getMonth();
if(currentMonth == 1) {
console.log('Вот он, високосный год! -- ', year);
break;
} else {
console.log('Фига вам, а не високосный год!');
}
}` Кроме момента, что если текущий год високосный, то он и будет получен.

Comment: Хотя я бы его ещё сократил до такого: `let now = new Date();
let year = now.getFullYear();
for (; ; --year) {
if (new Date(year, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1) {
break;
}
}
console.log(year)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let now = new Date();

for (let year = now.getFullYear(); year >= 0; year--) {
    let date = new Date(year, 2, 0);
    if (date.getDate() == 29) {
        console.log(year);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]